# Phonegap 3 and Eclipse - Why use together?

Tags: eclipse, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

I understand that phonegap 3 no longer requires Eclipse to compile the code and that this is now done directly via just the command line.

Apart from using Eclipse to right code in, is there any other advantages to using it, instead of just using sublime 2 ?

Would an advantage be that Eclipse has a built in android emulator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is really going to come down to personal preference. My choice is to use Aptana Studio (built on Eclipse) for development.

Eclipse does not have a built in android emulator. You need to install the Android SDK, build an AVD and install the Eclipse plugin. This will allow you to run your code inside of the Android emulator but it is not built in to Eclipse. The same could be done with Aptana Studio.

Comment: Thanks Dom, I will take a look at Aptana, you rate it above Eclipse? I have Eclipse set up ready to go as you describe, just preferences to what to develop in I guess!I also think the phonegap documentation is really unclear with the build process between pg3 and lower versions

Comment: Aptana is built on Eclipse but for some reason I do prefer Aptana over Eclipse. Eclipse just reminds me of learning Java and how much hatred I have for it so when I can I avoid Eclipse. Use what ever makes you comfortable. Phonegap docs could use a bit of cleaning up. Make sure that when you are viewing the docs you look in the upper right hand corner and ensure that the dropdown shows the Phonegap version number you are wanting to use.

Comment: Building aside, I find Eclipse invaluable for debugging Phonegap apps because you can read the log output of physical Android devices in real-time. Does Aptana allow you to do the same?

Comment: Not sure, I havent tried. I use phonegap build's debug service for that. https://build.phonegap.com/docs/advanced-debugging

Answer (score 0):

As long as you build the .apk with PhoneGap build or the CLI you only really need the Android SDK and specifically adb to debug effectively on a physical device or on the emulator.

I usually build and test most things in Chrome, then test specifics using an Android device running

```
adb logcat
```

There is no real use for Eclipse unless you actually want to use it (and for JavaScript, why would you?)